# Using tkinter gives spinning beachball on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter

Every time I try to run this program, the program gets stuck when dictee() is called. The famous spinning beachball on Mac. I found a similar problem, where window.update() was given a solution, but it did not work out. Either it just did not continue, or looped through the program.

Somehow it was working fine until I added the check() function to the game. I don't want to point in directions, but it helps providing that info.

I just started a few weeks ago learning about python to help my kid out. I wrote the script first without tkinter, that worked fine but decided to use tkinter to make it more 'attractive'.

What it basically needs to do is show a random word from the VOCABULARY list, create an entry window and compare the entry with the random word, update the score list, continue with a new word until VOCABULARY is empty on which it provides the choice of another round or quitting. This choice is also provided in between words so the user can quit any time.

Thanks.

````
"""import nescessary."""
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import random

#setup window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")
window.title("Aliyah's dictee spel")
window.configure(background = "black")

#my photo
photo1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="dictee.gif")
tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)

def main():
    """Setting up the game"""
    global VOCABULARY, WORDS_PASSED, WORDS_CORRECT, WORDS_WRONG
    VOCABULARY = ['kip', 'hok', 'bal', 'muis', 'gat']
    WORDS_PASSED = []
    WORDS_CORRECT = 0
    WORDS_WRONG = 0
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Label (window, text = "Dit is het dictee spel voor Aliyah. Wil je beginnen?", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=1)
    tk.Button(window, text="Ja", width=6, command=dictee) .grid(row=2, column=0)
    tk.Button(window, text="Nee", width=6, command=sys.exit) .grid(row=2, column=1)

def dictee():
    """Show random words and ask for input."""
    global ANSWER, WORD
    while True:
        if VOCABULARY == []:
            for widget in window.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()
            tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)
            tk.Label (window, text = "Dat waren alle woordjes.", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0)
            tk.Label (window, text = "Woordjes goed: %d" % WORDS_CORRECT, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=2, column=0)
            tk.Label (window, text = "Woordjes fout: %d" % WORDS_WRONG, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=3, column=0)
            tk.Label (window, text = "Wil je het nog een keer proberen?", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0)
            tk.Button(window, text="Ja", width=6, command=main) .grid(row=5, column=0)
            tk.Button(window, text="Nee", width=6, command=exit_game) .grid(row=5, column=1)
        else:
            for widget in window.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()
            WORD = random.choice(VOCABULARY)
            tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)
            tk.Label (window, text = "{}".format(WORD), bg="black", fg="white", font="none 20 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0)
            ANSWER = tk.Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
            ANSWER.grid(row=2, column=0)
            tk.Button(window, text="Check", width=6, command=check) .grid(row=3, column=0)
            WORDS_PASSED.append("{}".format(WORD))
            VOCABULARY.remove("{}".format(WORD))

def check():
    '''Cross check word shown with answer given'''
    global ANSWER, WORDS_CORRECT, WORDS_WRONG
    if ANSWER == WORD:
        tk.Label (window, text = "Wat goed!", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0)
        WORDS_CORRECT += 1
    else:
        tk.Label (window, text = "Jammer!", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0)
        WORDS_WRONG += 1

    tk.Label (window, text = "Wil je het nog een keer proberen?", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0)
    tk.Button(window, text="Ja", width=6, command=dictee) .grid(row=5, column=0)
    tk.Button(window, text="Nee", width=6, command=exit_game) .grid(row=5, column=1)

def exit_game():
    '''summarize results and exit after pushing enter'''
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Label (window, text = "Tot de volgende keer.", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0)
    tk.Label (window, text = "Woordjes goed: %d" % WORDS_CORRECT, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=2, column=0)
    tk.Label (window, text = "Woordjes fout: %d" % WORDS_WRONG, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=3, column=0)
    tk.Label (window, text = "Klik op OK om af te sluiten", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0)
    tk.Button(window, text="OK", width=6, command=sys.exit) .grid(row=5, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

window.mainloop()```
````

Comment: I think the while loop inside `dictee()` is not necessary and should be removed.

Comment: @acw1668 dude! How stupid of me :-) You're totally correct, the choice in between already takes it back to dictee() :-) It's fixed :-) How do I label this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop inside `dictee()` blocked tkinter from updating which caused the issue.

For your case, it is not necessary and can be removed.

Comment: Thanks! Although now I see another issue.. the check of ANSWER vs WORD is not working correctly. It acts like they don't match when they do, it continues with the {else} I also added WORD to the global definitions, which didn't work. Do you see anything?

Comment: The issue is caused by the line `if ANSWER == WORD:` inside `check()`.  As `ANSWER` is an `Entery`, it should be `if ANSWER.get() == WORD:` instead.